# object in a method?

Tags: java, class, methods

I doing a java exercise which I had to look at the solution. The main program looks like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PolarTest {

  public static Punkt tillPunkt(RPunkt pol) { 
    Punkt resultat = new Punkt();
    resultat.x = pol.r * Math.cos(pol.teta);
    resultat.y = pol.r * Math.sin(pol.teta);
    return resultat;
  }

  public static void main(String[] arg) {
    String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange polära koordinater");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
    RPunkt rp = new RPunkt();
    rp.r = sc.nextDouble();
    rp.teta = sc.nextDouble();
    Punkt p = tillPunkt(rp);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Som rektangulära koordinater (" + 
                                         p.x + ", " + p.y +")");     
  }
}
```

and a class names RPunkt in a separate file:

```
public class RPunkt {

  double r;
  double teta;

}
```

The thing with this code is that when I paste the code I get error saying that *Punkt cannot be solve as a type*. Is it because it's a method and not a class?

Update: There is no class Punkt in the solution...

Comment: No. It's because the code uses a class named Punkt that is not defined anywhere. The posted code only defines PolarTest and RPunkt.

Comment: Do you have a class `Punkt` defined somewhere?

Comment: No there is no class Punk in the solution :S. the author must have missed it...

Comment: Given the code, we can easily guess what the class Punkt looks like: `public class Punkt { double x; double y; }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are trying to create an object of type Punkt, but Punkt doesn't exist. You can only create an object of a class, not of a method.

```
   RPunkt rp = new RPunkt();
```

That above works right?

That is because RPunkt is a class.

Answer (score 0):

In this function, you have a return type of Punkt - do you have any definition for this?

```
public static Punkt tillPunkt(RPunkt pol) { 
Punkt resultat = new Punkt();
resultat.x = pol.r * Math.cos(pol.teta);
resultat.y = pol.r * Math.sin(pol.teta);
return resultat;
}
```